# Windows Phone 7 - Loading Animation

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

On the Windows Phone 7 device, when you run some of the standard apps (as well as the Facebook app), while the app is loading data it shows an animation of a series of dots that enter from the left and collect in the center of the screen and then exit from the right.

It seems to be a standard animation that is being used by many of the apps.

I was wondering if there is a standard animated image, or if there was sample code that would I could look at so that I could implement it in my application.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That is the ProgressBar with IsIndeterminate = true

You might like to check out this post for implementing it with a splash screen too.

[Creating a Splash Screen with a progress bar for WP7 applications. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications)

And these posts for implementing it in a performant manner.

[Jeff Wilcox – A high performance ProgressBar for Windows Phone](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127040027/https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/)

[Jeff Wilcox – Windows Phone performance progress bar update: part 2, remember to turn IsIndeterminate off when not needed!](https://web.archive.org/web/20201130192753/https://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/progressbarperftips2/)

Comment: +1. And I highly recommend using the PerformanceProgressBar at startup, I've been trying to push app authors to use it, cause on the device the stutter is really clear, since at startup they're super busy doing work on the UI thread.

Answer (score 6):

**This is an old obsolete answer if you are targeting Windows Phone 8 as performance issues have been resolved. You should use the `ProgressBar` in the Silverlight toolkit.**

The PerformanceProgressBar is probably still useful for Windows Phone 7 development.

See the note from Microsoft regarding the performance issues on this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442303(v=vs.105).aspx